# Eclipse no longer allows Shift-F

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I've just run into the strangest problem with Eclipse: When I type <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> into a text editor to produce "F", nothing happens. It's as if I didn't type anything. I can type <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in other programs (notepad, browsers, etc...) just fine. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> even works in other parts of Eclipse, such as any text field in the "Preferences". But the code editors (Java, XML, Properties, SQL, etc...) will not receive <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>. I've searched the "Keys" bindings to see if I somehow created a binding for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> but it doesn't appear to be the case. I've checked the Eclipse problem log but there's nothing in there related to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>. I've switched to a different workspace and found the problem occurs there as well. The only way for me to get the character "F" to appear in an editor is to either copy/paste it, or turn on caps lock, type <kbd>f</kbd>, and then turn off caps lock.

As an experiment, I created my own binding for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to "Find and Replace". When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, I immediately get the "Find and Replace" window. So the application is receiving <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, but not sending it to the text editors as a character... or something... :/

Does anyone have any idea what might have caused this, or how to undo it?

*Using Eclipse 4.3 (Juno)*

Comment: Did you install some plugin which magically overrides `shift+f`?

Comment: Check eclipse key bindings. Some plugins change them.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind: I've got the vrapper plugin installed and I've been using it quite happily for a few weeks now. Even if I disable it, I still have this problem.

Comment: @Adi: There is nothing bound to Shift+F.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your Eclipse or using a different (new) workspace?

Comment: @tobias_k: Problem is still present after workstation reboot. Problem is now present in other workspaces.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Was that a typo? Did you mean _not_ present in other workspaces? If you really meant _now_, was it not present in other workspaces before?

Comment: @tobias_k: I tried another workspace yesterday and the problem was there too. This problem was not present in *any* workspaces until yesterday.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind: well as it turns out, I updated an existing plugin and the update seems to have magically overridden `Shift-F`. Uninstalling the plugin got things working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know it sounds weird but it seems that this worked: I recalled that one of the logging plugins I had installed had updated yesterday. I uninstalled JLV and also LogViewer. Now <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> works again. I guess one of these plugins secretly bound to <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> but I couldn't find it in the regular "Keys" preferences page.

Comment: The problem was in JLV plugin. Now it is fixed by this issue: https://github.com/rdiachenko/jlv/issues/78